# Pass a C++ object to JAVA and back using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I am trying to implement a function that calls a function on main thread in C++ called `execute`. This is what I have so far:

```
//
// @brief  Allows intercommunication between main and secondary threads.
//
template <class... Args>
class Dispatcher final {
public:

#ifdef __APPLE__

    // iOS implementation
    static void execute(std::function<void(Args...)> handler, Args... args) {
        __block auto _args = std::move(args...);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            handler(std::move(_args));
        });
    }

#elif defined(__ANDROID__)

    static std::map<size_t, std::pair<std::function<void(Args...)>, Args...>> _callableMapping;
    static size_t _lastId;

    // Android implementation
    static void execute(std::function<void(Args...)> handler, Args... args) {
        auto callable = std::make_pair(std::move(handler), std::move(args...));
        // store the callable in a map
        _callableMapping.insert(std::make_pair(++_lastId, callable));
        ...
        // call a Java method that calls runOnUiThread() which in turn calls
        // a JNIEXPORT function, which calls
        // __handleExecutionOnMainThread with the same ID that is passed in
    }

    static void __handleExecutionOnMainThread(size_t callableId) {
        auto& mapping = _callableMapping.find(callableId)->second;
        // call the function with arguments
        mapping->first(std::move(mapping->second...));
    }
#endif

};
```

The problem is that when I call __handleExecutionOnMainThread from the JNIEXPORT function, I need to provide template parameter for `Dispatcher<Args...>`, which are not known at this point.

I then thought of a different approach. Is it possible to pass a C++ object (i.e. the pair of `std::function` and its args stored in `auto callable` in function `execution`) to JAVA where it wouldn't be used (I imagine it could be stored as `object`) and pass it back via `runOnUiThread` back to C++ to be executed in `__handleExecutionOnMainThread`?

I hope the problem is understandable. If not, I can explain in more detail.

Comment: Rather than a pair of function and arguments you could store a `function<void()>` by binding the callable to the arguments, e.g. via a lambda, before storing it.

Comment: Can you provide a trivial example of how to do that?